# Combine multiple JavaScript files into one JS file - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using a *WordPress* site and after running the Pingdom tools speed test they suggested me to combine the external JavaScript for my website.

**How can I do this?**

I don't want to install any new plugin and am currently using "WP-Rocket" which is not doing the job well with combining the JS-files although I checked the box for that alternative.

Comment: I'm voting to move this question to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ since it isn't a programming question. As a side note: try browsing wordpress plugins with `minify` tag

Comment: @RuslanBes Sure do that.